# Using rails3-jquery-autocomplete from a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, belongs-to

I receive this error when I type an existing topic into the topic field of my form:

```
Started GET "/posts/autocomplete_topic_name?term=test" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-21 10:51:19 -0700
  Processing by PostsController#show as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"test", "id"=>"autocomplete_topic_name"}
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 0 LIMIT 1
Completed   in 28ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post with ID=autocomplete_topic_name):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:9:in `show'

Rendered /home/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.5ms)
Rendered /home/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.2ms)
Rendered /home/dude/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (14.2ms)
```

The topics "test" and "testing" exist.

models:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many        :posts
  validates       :name, :presence => true,
  attr_accessible :name, :post_id
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :topic
  attr_accessible :name, :title, :content, :topic, :topic_attributes
end
```

view:

/posts/new renders only this form: (uses simple_form)

```
<%= simple_form_for :post, :url => { :controller => :posts, :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <h1>Create a Post</h1>
  <%= f.input :name, :label => false, :placeholder => "Name (optional)", :required => false %>
  <%= f.input :title, :label => false, :placeholder => "Title" %>
  <%= f.input :content, :label => false, :placeholder => "Content", :as => :text %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :topic do |topic_form| %>
    <%= topic_form.input :name, :label => false, :placeholder => "Topic", :url => autocomplete_topic_name_path, :as => :autocomplete %>
  <% end %>
  <%= raw recaptcha_tags -%>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Post" %>  
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :topic, :name, :full => true
  respond_to :html, :js, :xml

  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  def create
    topic_name = params[:post].delete(:topic)
    @topic = Topic.find_or_create_by_name(topic_name)
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.topic = @topic
    respond_to do |format|
      if verify_recaptcha(:model => @post) && @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@post, :notice => 'Post was successfully created.') }
      else
        flash.delete(:recaptcha_error)
        flash.now[:error] = "Incorrect word verification. Are you sure you\'re human?"
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Line 9 of the Posts controller is:

```
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
```

in the posts#show

routes.rb:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "posts#index"
  resources :topics
  resources :posts
  resources :comments
  match "posts/autocomplete_topic_name", :as => "autocomplete_topic_name"
end
```

Here's my gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'ancestry'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.3'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'nifty-generators'
gem 'rdiscount'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'recaptcha', :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
gem 'simple_form'
```

and schema:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "title"
  t.text     "content"
  t.integer  "topic_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "topics", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your routes file, try moving the "match 'posts/...'" line before "resources :posts".

Comment: Thank you so much. I was convinced it was my controller code.